# Unable to compile this Visual Basic program

Tags: vb.net

So I was given a sample Visual Basic code and asks to run the function given within the code. When I compile it on online VB compilers it doesn't run, it returns the following error messages:

- error VBNC30203: Identifier expected. (lines 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 22)
- error VBNC30037: Symbol is not valid. (lines 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21)

And the following is the code I asked for this question:

```
Function ???? (data As Integer(), val As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
        If data(i) = val Then
            Return True
        End If
    End For
    Return False
End Function

data:
|----|----|----|----|----|
|  2 |  6 | -3 |  3 |  7 |
|----|----|----|----|----|
val: 5

data:
|----|----|----|----|----|
| -1 |  8 |  2 | -4 |  9 |
|----|----|----|----|----|
val: 2
```

Comment: Try replacing `End For` with `Next i`

Comment: @BigBen yup. `{array}.Length` gives it away. And the `Return` statements. And the VBNCxxxxx error codes :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I saw the `.Length` and `Return`. The VBNC.... error code is a new one for me. I never program in VB, thanks for confirming!

Comment: It looks like your homework is requiring you to read the code, understand what it does, and then give the function a meaningful name and get it to compile. Not sure what you're expecting from us though. Hint: the "data" part is not part of the function's code.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put the function inside the `Module` block. After this you need to change the name of the function ???? to a valid name. And the `For` block finishes with the `next` word like this:

```
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
    End Sub

function functionName (data As Integer(), val As Integer)  As Boolean

Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
        If data(i) = val Then
            Return True
        End If
    next
    Return False
End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function ???? (data As Integer(), val As Integer) As Boolean
```

This is your declaration of a Function. It is currently named ????, which will not work as a name for the code basis. It takes in two arguments, an array of integers (data), and an integer to be found in the array (val), and returns a Boolean (True/False value).

```
Dim i As Integer
```

Declaration of an integer named i

```
For i = 0 To data.Length - 1  
    If data(i) = val Then
        Return True
    End If
End For
Return False
```

For loop running over the integer values from 0 to the length of the array data (imported from the function). If the value is found within the array, it returns `True`, if it is not found, it returns `False`

```
End Function
```

The end of the function. This is where it would return to whatever module called the function.

```
data:
|----|----|----|----|----|
|  2 |  6 | -3 |  3 |  7 |
|----|----|----|----|----|
val: 5
```

For this data, the function should return `False`, as there is no occurrence of 5 within the data.

```
data:
|----|----|----|----|----|
| -1 |  8 |  2 | -4 |  9 |
|----|----|----|----|----|
val: 2
```

For this data, the function should return `True`, as the number 2 shows up in array space 2 (Remember, arrays start at 0).

This is, honestly, a question I would expect to see on Chegg, not on StackOverflow.